# Node.js/Firebase: can't set headers after they're sent

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

We have an express.js/firebase project with an /api/progress POST route that takes a marker as a parameter and increments it if the scanned marker equals the current progress of the user in an array that stores a story order. For that, we have a GET route /api/progress that returns the user progress. We check if the number of the scanned marker equals the storyOrder[userProgress] (minus one because of array indices), user progress is obtained from the api/progress/?user="user" route.

When `Number(marker) === storyOrder[response.data.data]-1`, we increment the progress in the firebase database by one. However, when the code is run, it sometimes produces the following error:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at userDB.on.data (file:///Users/user/Documents/projects/project/routes/api.mjs:104:15)
at /Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:4465:22
at exceptionGuard (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:691:9)
at EventList.raise (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9727:17)
at EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ (/Users/user/Documents/projects/project/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:9681:41)
```

This is the code for the /api/progress GET and POST routes:

GET progress:

```
router.get('/progress', async (req, res, next) => {
let name = req.query.user || null;
console.log('Name: ',name);
let progress;
let dataList;

try {
  const getData = async data => {
    if (data.val()) {
    let tmp = await data.val();
    progress = parseInt(tmp[name].progressCounter);
    console.log(progress);
    // Return progress
    res.json({ status: 200, data: progress });
  } else {
    res.json({ status: 500, err: 'No data! ' });
  }
};

const errData = error => {
  console.error('Something went wrong.');
  console.error(error);
};

dataList = await userDB
  .orderByKey()
  .equalTo(name)
  .on('value', getData, errData);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message)
  res.json({ status: 500, err: 'Error while getting progress' });
}

});
```

POST progress:

```
router.post('/progress', async (req, res, next) => {
const user = req.session.user;
const marker = req.body.marker;
if (marker!== undefined) {
  const updateProgress = async progress => {
  let updateProg = progress.data;
  updateProg++;
  await userDB.child(user).update({ progressCounter: updateProg });
  res.json({ status: 200, marker: updateProg });
};
axios
  .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/progress?user=${user}`)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(storyOrder[response.data.data]-1);
    if (Number(marker) === storyOrder[response.data.data]-1) {
      updateProgress(response.data);
    } else {
      res.status(304);
      res.json({ status: 304 });
    }
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}else{
  res.json({status: 304})
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because, your calling res.send() in the middle of your function and the code continues

This piece of code is called

```
const getData = async data => {
    if (data.val()) {
    let tmp = await data.val();
    progress = parseInt(tmp[name].progressCounter);
    console.log(progress);
    // Return progress
    res.json({ status: 200, data: progress });
  } else {
    res.json({ status: 500, err: 'No data! ' });
  }
```

since an error occurs, is called

```
res.json({ status: 500, err: 'No data! ' });
```

And then this

```
dataList = await userDB
  .orderByKey()
  .equalTo(name)
  .on('value', getData, errData);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error: ', err.message)
  res.json({ status: 500, err: 'Error while getting progress' });
}
```

That will call again the first piece of code with a new res.json, but since the response was already sent, you get that error